# The command "sudo apt-get update" always ocurred errors

Tags: c++11, ubuntu-12.04, g++4.8

The old g++/gcc version on my computer is 4.6.3. I need to update it to 4.8, because some softwares I want to install are required.

But when I update g++/gcc on ubuntu 12.04 as follow command, there were some errors.

```html
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

I can run the first command well.

```html
myshu@ubuntu-headnode:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Toolchain test builds; see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp4H9X2n/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp4H9X2n/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key BA9EF27F from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp4H9X2n/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key BA9EF27F: public key "Launchpad Toolchain builds" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

But the "sudo apt-get update" always have errors.

```html
myshu@ubuntu-headnode:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:1 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]                                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                                                                                                                          
Get:2 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]                                                                                                                 
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise Release                                                                                                                                        
Get:3 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates Release [55.4 kB]                                                                                                         
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports Release                                                                                                                                                  
Get:4 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security Release [55.5 kB]                                                                                                                  
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/main Sources                                                                                                                                                           
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/restricted Sources                                                                                                                            
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/universe Sources                                                                                         
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/multiverse Sources                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                                                                                      
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                  
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                                                                                                      
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                                    
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                                                 
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                                                 
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                                                                             
Get:5 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/main Sources [500 kB]                                                                       
Get:6 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [72 B]                                                                                                              
Get:7 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [8,835 B]                                                                                             
Get:8 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [134 kB]                                                              
Get:9 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [10.5 kB]                                                                                        
Get:10 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,050 kB]                                                                                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                                                                                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                                                                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                               
Get:11 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.4 kB]                                                                              
Get:12 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [285 kB]                                                                                                                     
Get:13 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [17.1 kB]                                                                                                               
Get:14 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [1,126 kB]                                                                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                                                             
Get:15 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.4 kB]                                                                                      
Get:16 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [294 kB]                                                                                           
Get:17 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [17.3 kB]                                                                                     
Get:18 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [208 B]                                                                                             
Get:19 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [202 B]                                                                           
Get:20 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex [202 B]                                                                           
Get:21 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [205 B]                                                                             
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/main Sources                                                                             
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/universe Sources                                                                         
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                                                            
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                                      
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                      
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                                                         
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex                                                                                          
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                                    
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                                    
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex                                                                                      
Get:22 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/main Sources [146 kB]                                                                                        
Get:23 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [4,636 B]                                                                                 
Get:24 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/universe Sources [55.3 kB]                                                                                   
Get:25 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [3,035 B]                                                                                 
Get:26 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [668 kB]                                                                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                                           
Get:27 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.8 kB]                                                                                    
Get:28 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [141 kB]                                                                                         
Get:29 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,352 B]                                                                                     
Get:30 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [741 kB]                                                                                               
Get:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources [1,600 B]                                                                                                        
Get:32 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [10.8 kB]                                                                                                                 
Get:33 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [149 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:34 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,533 B]                                                                                                                 
Get:35 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [208 B]                                                                                                                         
Get:36 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [199 B]                                                                                                                       
Get:37 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [202 B]                                                                                                      
Get:38 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [205 B]                                                                                                        
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                  
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                                      
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                                                                                      
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise/universe Translation-en                                                                                                        
Get:39 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [432 kB]                                                                                                              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                              
Get:40 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en [10.1 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:41 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,690 B]                                                                                                                        
Get:42 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [172 kB]                                                                                                                           
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                              
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en                                                                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en                                                                                                                         
Get:43 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [270 kB]                                                                                                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                      
Get:44 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,993 B]                                                                                                                           
Get:45 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en [2,805 B]                                                                                                       
Get:46 http://mirrors.sohu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [90.4 kB]                                                                                                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                                                                               
Get:47 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages [25.7 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                           
Get:48 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages [3,396 B]                                                                                                                                                                                            
Get:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en [1,556 B]                                                                                                                                                                                           
Ign http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org jessie Release.gpg                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Ign http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org jessie Release            
Ign http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org jessie/main TranslationIndex
Err http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
  Undetermined Error [IP: 130.226.56.135 80]
Err http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org jessie/main i386 Packages
  Undetermined Error [IP: 130.226.56.135 80]
Ign http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org jessie/main Translation-en
Fetched 6,537 kB in 10min 14s (10.6 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org/repos/deb/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Undetermined Error [IP: 130.226.56.135 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.secondarymetabolites.org/repos/deb/dists/jessie/main/binary-i386/Packages  Undetermined Error [IP: 130.226.56.135 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone help me to solves this problem?

Comment: It's a better question for http://askubuntu.com and should be migrated there.

Comment: @PaulRooney I'll try that.